# Equation - Math.Round and double

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, math, double

I'm working on an equation for conversion rate. My current problem is I'm not sure if I'm getting the correct results.

In the Linq query when creating the `GC_ConversionRateModel`, I'm dividing `TotalOrders` with `Visitors` to get the conversion. In order to get a fluent result in Google Charts, I have to use 4 decimals, multiply the result with 100 and finally display the result with 2 decimals. (Not decimal data type).

Is this a good way to do this?

```
OrdersList.ForEach(o =>
        {
            TotalConversions.Add((from v in VisitorsList
                                  where v.Date == o.Date
                                  select new GC_ConversionRateModel(o.Date, (double)o.TotalOrders / (double)v.Visitors)).FirstOrDefault());

        });


        foreach (var conv in TotalConversions)
        {
            conv.ConversionRate = Math.Round(conv.ConversionRate, 4); // -- Round to 4 decimals
            conv.ConversionRate = conv.ConversionRate * 100; //-- Multiply with 100
            conv.ConversionRate = Math.Round(conv.ConversionRate, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven); //-- Round to 2 decimals


        }
     return TotalConversions;
```

Thx

Comment: do you have any _particular_ problem about using this way ?

Comment: What results are you getting? How are they incorrect?

Comment: Well when debugging i get XX:XX but i was expected XX:XXXX when round by 4. Meaby iv'e missunderstood nad round by 4 is suposed to generate the format XX:XX (2 digits on left and 2 digits on right as suposed to 4 digits on the right)

Comment: @KristofferAndersson That is not what should be happening ([demo](http://ideone.com/4mRx5e)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second rounding line of your code never does anything useful because of the first rounding line: once you rounded to four decimal places, the number is going to look like this:

```
##.####00000
```

When you multiply by 100, the decimal dot will move two places to the right, so the number is going to look like this:

```
####.##00000
```

Note that the number has exactly two decimal digits, so the call of

```
conv.ConversionRate = Math.Round(conv.ConversionRate, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
```

has no effect.

You can safely replace the three lines of conversion with one:

```
conv.ConversionRate = Math.Round(100*conv.ConversionRate, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, very useful. Less is more =)